# Trouble when editing Vue Data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

If I have data like so in Vue JS 2:

```
data : {
  newBus: {
    name: '',
    hours: {
      sunday: '',
    }
  }
}
```

And I set it here:

```
<input v-model="newBus.hours.sunday" type="text" placeholder="Sunday">
```

Adding a business this way works, the issue comes when I try to update them. The user clicks on the item from a list and then the saved data fills in the form like so:

```
<div v-for="bus in businesses" v-on:click="editBus(bus)" class="list-group-item bus-list-item">{{bus.name}}</div>
```

Method:

```
editBus: function (bus) { 
    /*Set post values to form*/
    this.newBus = bus
  },
```

But I get the error:

> vue.js:1453 TypeError: Cannot read property 'sunday' of undefined

This happens immediately when the item to be updated is clicked. Any ideas?

EDIT: It appears to be related to the `hours` property not being avaliable on `bus`. If I `console.log(bus)` it doesn't show. But I need to add this data to this business. Is there a way to have it ignore data it doesn't yet have? What I don't understand is that if it was not nested...aka `sunday: ''` instead of `hours: { sunday: ''}` it works fine.

EDIT: Here is the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/mmEERL) recreation.

Comment: v-on:click="editBus(bus)" is that a typo? I think you mean editBus(business) or v-for="bus in businesses"

Comment: Yes, v-for bus in businesses... my mistake.

Comment: Do you still have the problem? If so, you should provide more code samples to help understand what's going on.

Comment: Yup, I just typed it wrong in question. I'll update with more content.

Comment: @Robodude I was able to hack together the same error in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/mmEERL) Error is in the console. Adding CodePen to original question.

Comment: Isn't it something related to object's reactivity in vuejs? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: @choasia it looks like it, but why does that work if not nested data? Such as data:{name:} vs data:{sub:{name: ""}}. One works, one doesn't. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here isn't really a Vue problem it's a Javascript problem. **You cannot access a property of undefined**.

Using the example data structure from your pen.

```
newComment: {
    name: '',
    comment: '',
    votes:  0,
    time:  timeStamp(),
    subcomment: {
        name: ''
    }
}
```

In this case, you've set everything up with a defined value, so everything is going to be resolved. The problem comes when you are clicking your edit button, the object received looks like this:

```
{
    name: "some name",
    comment: "some comment",
    time: "4/5/2017",
    votes: 145,
    .key: "-Kh0PVK9_2p1oYmzWEjJ"
}
```

Note here that there is *no* `subcomment` property. That means that the result of *this code*

```
newComment.subcomment
```

is `undefined`. But in your template, you go on to reference

```
newComment.subcomment.name
```

So you are essentially trying to get the `name` property of `undefined`. There is no `name` property of `undefined`. That is why you get your error.

One way you can protect yourself from this error is to check to make sure the `subcomment` property exists before rendering the element using `v-if` (forgive me if this is the wrong pug syntax-I'm not that familiar with it)

```
input#name(type="text")(placeholder="Name")(v-model="newComment.subcomment.name")(v-if="newComment.subcomment")
```

That will prevent the error.

Alternatively in your `editComment` method, you could check to see if `subcomment` exists, and if it doesn't, add it.

```
if (!comment.subcomment)
    comment.subcomment = {name: ''}
this.newComment = comment
```

Finally, you ask, why does it work if it's not nested data. The key difference is this: if `newComment` exists, say like this

```
newComment: {}
```

and you try to get `newComment.name` then the returned value of `name` is `undefined`. If you have a template that has something like `v-model="newComment.name"` nothing is going to crash, it's just going to set the value of the input element to undefined, and when you change it, `newComment.name` will get the updated value.

In other words, when you try to reference `newComment.subcomment.name` **you are trying to reference the name property of something that doesn't exist** whereas when you try to reference `newComment.name`, the object exists, and it doesn't have the `name` property.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation! And you even provided me a way to add the data which is what I would need in my case to work with existing data. Thanks!